# React hooks useEffect running even with [] given as deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing quite a weird issue. Below is the code

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => setCount(count => count + 1), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
};
```

As per my knowledge, since I have given an empty array, the useEffect will only run after the first render. Also, since I am clearing the interval COUNT MUST NOT BE UPDATED AFTER COUNT=1. Still the setInterval seems to be running continuously. Can anyone please explain it?

Is it so that since I am given [] as deps the interval is somehow not being cleared?

Comment: No, the function you return only gets called after the component unmounts.  There is nothing telling the interval to stop.

Comment: I think you are confusing setInterval with setTimeout

Answer (score 3):

`clearInterval(id)` - this will get invoked just before component gets unmounted. As long as the component is not unmounted the function returned from useEffect will not invoked. So the interval in not cleared and the state will continue updating thus the count increases. The interval gets cleared when the component `Counter` gets unmounted

Comment: As per the React docs

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. **This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time**. We’ll discuss why this helps avoid bugs and how to opt out of this behavior in case it creates performance issues later below.

Answer (score 1):

The effect is *only* setting up the interval callback to update your state. `setInterval` will continue to run on the interval, use `setTimeout` instead to only run the state update once. Still return a `clearTimeout` in case the component unmounts within the timeout period.

**Edit:** More Detailed Explanation

By using an empty dependency array you are telling react that running your effect isn't dependent on any external values. The effect will run once when the component mounts (setting up the `setInterval`) and ***never run again*** since it isn't ***dependent*** on anything. When the component is unmounting react will run all the returned effect "cleanup" functions, i.e. the `clearInterval` call.

What this leaves you with is this:

1. Component mounts
2. Effect runs: sets up interval, returns cleanup function
3. interval is running

   - update count after 1000ms
   - update count after 1000ms
   - update count after 1000ms
   - update count after 1000ms
4. Component unmounts: react runs effect cleanup function, clears interval

**Suggested Fix:** Use `setTimeout` to only update state once

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => setCount(count => count + 1), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.

Yes, React will clean up **before running the effects next time**, not **right after running the current effects**.

Here's a brief explanation.

[image]

In your case, `clearInterval(id)` will only be executed when the Counter component is unmounted.

edited: 
I have created a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-timing-dlro2) to show when the effect is executed. Based on this example I updated my original "graph" because it looks react run the "clean effect" after rerendering.

Comment: I think it makes sense, can you please help me with a reference? Like where could I find this? 

Also, if I wanted to run the setInterval only during the first render, I can't do it with useEffects? I'll have to consider useRef for this case?

Comment: It's mostly based on my observation by doing `console.log`s. I just created a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-timing-dlro2). The best reference I can find is [the official hooks api document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect).

Comment: If you want to run setInterval only during the first render, you should be able to use `React.useEffect(() => {...}, []);`. Is there any problem of using it?